# Running SQL Agent JOB that calls SSIS on another server and get Nt Authority\Anonymous login errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

The current issue is our main server is having CPU resource issues between SSIS and SQL Server 2017 Standard.  So in researching, I found that if load the SSIS Catalog on Server B you can execute that package From Server A by changing the Package server in the job step From Server A to server B.  We have confirmed that the package does fire on Server B and fails with login fail for NT Authority\Anonoymous Login.

Both servers are running useing the same AD Account. User is a sys admin on both servers.
Updated owner of job to service account.
Create credentials with service account and still had the same issue.

Comment: the SQL Agent service account is not the same as the SQL Server service account... https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204326/login-failed-for-user-nt-authority-anonymous-logon-for-ssis

Comment: Server and Agent using same account on both servers.

Comment: Have you try changing the owner to 'sa' on the job properties window?